# Chinese Dotted/Dashed Line font?

Tags: simplified-characters, handwriting, fonts

Anybody knows where to get this Chinese font type?

[image: Dotted font]

Comment: http://www.ddooo.com/softdown/51296.htm

Comment: @tinysunlight, I followed your link, but where should one click to save the font? I clicked the big green button written 立即下载 (download immediately). But it's getting to a .exe file, what looks like a virus to me.

Comment: @Rodrigo click the tiny 本地高速下载 under the bunch of ads

Comment: @Rodrigo click link under其它下载地址

Comment: Your tag says simplified Chinese, but the font is traditional. I was hoping there was a simplified version of this font, as it could be quite handy :(

Comment: There's no such kind of font in Simplified Chinese that I can find. But if you really need it, I think I can create one for you.

Comment: @xfx is there by any chance you already make the chinese dotted simplified font? I'm from Indonesia - Jakarta, I need your help to make the dotted chinese font for my kids to help them learn mandarin. Thanks! 谢谢！

Answer (score 2):

Simply try "中文字体 虚线体" in Google, you will find many results.

OK, here are some resources:
[华康标楷虚线体](http://www.sozi.cn/ziti/201009092755.html)
[金梅美工虚线体](http://www.sozi.cn/ziti/201009183666.html)

I tried a few, they are all traditional Chinese font type, can't find simplified Chinese version.

Comment: This answer is good as it shows how we can find the answer, but not good enough as it hasn't directly answered the question. IMO, it's better to name a few examples.